# Algolia Magento site search disabled - record quota exceeded

Tags: magento, algolia

I've installed Algoila on my Magento store a while ago. Suddenly it stopped working and reverted back to the original Magento search.

When I've checked the settings it was showing that the Admin API Key was missing. I've re-entered it but on search this error appeared: 
An error occurred while saving this configuration: Record quota exceeded, change plan or delete records.

http://prntscr.com/d300va

When checking in Algolia Dashboard I can see that there are only 6k out of 10k records.
http://prntscr.com/d304fw

Does anybody have any suggestions?

I'm using magento 1.9.2.0 and Algoila extension version 1.7.2

Thanks a bunch.
I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the Magento re-indexing process, the number of records will increase if there are multiple sort orders defined (to achieve the best performance possible the index for each sort is pre-computed and stored+queried separately). For quota purposes, this means one record per sort order. This could be the cause of going over quota when it appears that you have less records.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I've just sent the email.